# Reliably read n bytes from file

Tags: python

I have a python program that needs to read `N` bytes from a file at certain offset (and write to another file). This is currently done using python's low-level interface `os.read()`, not file object due to other reasons. The file has been `stat()`, so it is certain that much data exists. My question is, will python try its best to return `N` bytes, or do I need to do it as it was coded in C, where such read needs to be put in a loop, check returned bytes for each read, until `N` bytes has been read. I hope this is to be avoided if python is already doing that internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.read()` is a low-level call using the C stdlib calls *directly*, only translating between Python and C types. See the [source code for the POSIX version](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4ad1ea911fd0/Modules/posixmodule.c#l6752) for example.

You'll have to treat it exactly like a C call; you'll have to loop just like you would in C code.

Comment: If so, do I have any meaningful performance gains if such logic is coded in C extension (vs. python implementation)? or since it is low-level calls already, it doesn't matter much?

Comment: It is as low level as you can get from pure Python code. You are doing I/O, any performance gains are sunk into the pit that is a harddisk.

Answer (score 0):

`os.read` could even do EINTR on signals (Python 3.2), see for example [this bug entry in the issue database](http://bugs.python.org/issue10956). The behaviour *should* be fixed W.R.T. `EINTR` semantics in upcoming [Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/).